# how mysql `select where in` query work ? why larger amount parameter faster?

Tags: mysql, algorithm, select

I am doing query with SELECT WHERE IN, and found something unpredicted,

1. `SELECT a,b,c FROM tbl1 where a IN (a1,a2,a3...,a5000)` --> this query took 1.7ms
2. `SELECT a,b,c FROM tbl1 where a IN (a1,a2,a3...,a20)` --> this query took 6.4ms

what is the algorithm of IN ? why larger amount of parameter faster than smaller one ?

Answer (score 0):

The following is a guess...

For every SQL query, the optimizer analyzes the query to choose which index to use.

For multi-valued range queries (like `IN(...)`), the optimizer performs an "index dive" for each value in the short list, trying to estimate whether it's a good idea to use the index. If you are searching for values that are too common, it's more efficient to just do a table-scan, so there's no need to use the index.

MySQL 5.6 introduced a special optimization, to skip the index dives if you use a long list. Instead, it just guesses that the index on your `a` column may be worth using, based on stored index statistics.

You can control how long of a list causes the optimizer to skip index dives with the `eq_range_index_dive_limit` option. The default is 10. Your example shows a list of length 20, so I'm not sure why it's more expensive.

Read the manual about this feature here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/range-optimization.html#equality-range-optimization